# Broken file names in Files columns while using S3 bucket parse-server

Tags: node.js, swift, parse-platform, amazon-s3, parse-server

My Parse Server has been successfully configured and deployed. However I am blocked from pushing an app update for the following reason. On my new infrastructure all new files are being stored in my s3 bucket. All users who haven't updated will not be able to see these files or if existing users update and upload a new photo. I looked at the parse.com dashboard to see what was happening and this was what I found.

[image]

The file that says "ilePicture.png" is the newly changed file. So it is updating that column in my database. However when I go to download it I get this:

[image]

For users on the new infrastructure they can get the new and old files. But for those who have not updated they cannot see the new s3 files.

On github here was someone's observations:

> The issue is because the substring of 37 characters, but in case the
>   S3 (at least, i don't know about other file store services) the uuid
>   of the file generated is missing the dashes, so the length of the uuid
>   is 33 instead 37.
>
> Possible solution is to avoid the length based calculation, and use
>   indexOf(""), and this will be a good solution for it, but needs to
>   check first if tfss is found, since there, theres no "" separating the
>   name from the uuid.

Comment: I'm getting this issue on new installations of the s3 adapter. How did you fix this?